# How to install SignalR.Client.NET35 to a project

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, signalr

I am using SignalR 0.5.3, installed via NuGet, for my .NET 4.5 Web Application - now, since I need to push data from SQL SERVER 2008R2 (supporting only the .NET Framework up to 3.5), I need to create a library using the SignalR .NET 3.5 Client.

I have seen in the [project website](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR) that there is probably a SignalR.Client.NET35 version but (being not very familiar neither with github nor with NuGet) I have no clue how to install that client for the library project I have to work on.
I have tried installing with the std command `install-package SignalR.Client` but the message i get is:

```
Install-Package : Could not install package 'SignalR.Client 0.5.3'.
You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 
'.NETFramework,Version=v3.5', but the package does not contain any assembly 
references that are compatible with that framework. 
For more information, contact the package author.
```

so it looks like the right .NET version is not picked correctly/out of the box.

Before bothering the author, i thought to give a try round here.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Forgot to mention, I know I can download the source code, include in my Project and reference in the library project - I am wondering if there any solution through NuGet though. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We haven't packaged the 3.5 client into the package as yet. You'll need to build from source.

Answer (score 0):

I backported the v1.x and v2.x SignalR clients to NET 3.5. Available as NuGet packages here: http://www.nuget.org/packages/Nivot.SignalR.Client.Net35/